# how do I tell tar to only exclude a directory off of the root but not a directory with the same name deeper in the tree?

Tags: tar, directory-structure

Folder structure:

```
etc (dir)
deploy (dir)
src (dir)
config (dir)
dist
 ├- config (dir) 
 ├- index.js
```

What I'd like to do is pack up everything except the root config folder and place it in a tar in `deploy`. It's important that the `dist/config` folder be present in the output. Started with:

```
tar -czf deploy/deploy.gz   --exclude=deploy  --exclude="./config/"  ./*

$ l ./deploy/deploy0/dist 
index.js
router.js
test
```

But that results in a missing `dist/config`. The only way I can get `dist/config` to come over is if I don't try to exclude anything named config:

```
tar -czf deploy/deploy.gz   --exclude=deploy   ./*

$ l ./deploy/deploy1/dist 
config
index.js
router.js
test
```

OSX and CentOS (dev and build). The man for [tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html) makes me think this is not possible.

I worked around this by just deleting folders I don't want, since this is in a build environment and the files are disposable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find` to create your arguments - a bit longish though:

```
 find -mindepth 1 ! -wholename './config' ! -wholename './config/*'
```

`mindepth 1` to exclude `.`, and two `wholename` exclutions for the directory itself, as well as its contents.

```
tar -xzf deploy/deploy.gz --exclude="deploy" \
$( find -mindepth 1 ! -wholename './config' ! -wholename './config/*' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dot reference to the current directory as an archive root is an anchor:

```bash
tar --exclude='./deploy' --exclude='./config' -cvf deploy/deploy.tar .
```

But if you use a directory name or a wildcard, then the `--anchored` flag will come to the help:

```bash
tar --anchored --exclude=deploy --exclude=config -cvf deploy/deploy.tar *
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put `--exclude` options before the source, destination args

```
tar --exclude=deploy --exclude="./config" -cvz deploy/deploy.gz .
```

Comment: `tar: Option --exclude./config is not supported`

Comment: fixed this typo to --exclude="./config"

Answer (score 0):

With that skeleton directory tree:

```
mkdir -p src config dist/config
```

GNU tar seems to do what you want if you use `--exclude="./config"` (without the trailing slash):

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
$ tar cf - --exclude="./config" ./* | tar tf -
./dist/
./dist/config/
./src/
```

However, the `tar` on my OS X (`bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`) seems to drop both copies of `config` with that same command line.

So, one way to work around it seems to use GNU tar. :)

Another would be to make the archive one directory level higher, and include the top-level directory in it (as is customary with Unix software), so we can use its name on the `exclude`:

```
$ cd ..
$ tar cf - --exclude="dir/config" dir/* | tar tf -
dir/dist/
dir/dist/config/
dir/src/
```

Or, if you have a shell that supports it, use `extglob` to match everything but the one name:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ tar cf - ./!(config)  | tar tf -
./dist/
./dist/config/
./src/
```

Or use any other way to remove one item from the list of file names, which should be simple if you know your top-level file names don't contain anything more special than alphanumerics (especially no whitespace).

Comment: "Another would be to make the archive one directory level higher" unfortunately not an option in a build system -- I'm locked in to that directory by design, unable to edit directories outside of it

Comment: Add `^` to your top-level `--exclude` like this: `tar cf - --exclude="^config" ./* | tar tf -` I had the same problem on macos and this fixes that. Later configs won't match, because the ^ causes a match only at the start of the line, and later ones will have path prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `./` marker at the beginning of your excluded files.

I use it this way:

```bash
tar --exclude='./build.tar.gz' --exclude='./config' -czf build.tar.gz .
```